# how can i read data from firebase realtime database when i want and not just when DataChange

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Everything was working fine except I wanted to secure my database and so I had to make requests with references. When I did the query on the whole database it worked great, but when I wanted to query with different references it didn't work. I have to wait to read a data (the value of the "shared" variable) then with this data I have to get the latitude and longitude of these users.
To sum it up, I just want to be able to read data from the realtime firebase database whenever I want and not just when the data in the database changes. Here is my code and database. Thanks in advance

this is my code which works but doesn't do a request with a reference so i can't secure my database with this code.

```
mdatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
        // whenever data at this location is updated.
        nom = "jacque";
        String partage,pers;
        String[] partage2 ;
        ArrayList<String> accèsposition = new ArrayList<String>();
        partage = dataSnapshot.child("solal").child("partagé").getValue().toString();
        partage2 = partage.split(",");
        System.out.println(partage2);
        Log.i("2", Arrays.toString(partage2));
        for (int i = 0; i < partage2.length; i++) {
            pers = partage2[i];
            latitude = Double.parseDouble(dataSnapshot.child(pers).child("lat").getValue().toString());
            longitude = Double.parseDouble(dataSnapshot.child(pers).child("lon").getValue().toString());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,pers+latitude+longitude,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println(pers+latitude+longitude);
            ajouterunpoint(pers,latitude,longitude);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed to read value
        Log.w("2", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
    }
});
```

that's the new code that didn't work

```
DatabaseReference ref2 = database.getReference("solal/partagé");
    // Read from the database
    ref2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            nom = "jacque";
            String partage,pers;
            ArrayList<String> accèsposition = new ArrayList<String>();
            partage = snapshot.getValue().toString();
            partage2 = partage.split(",");
            Log.i("2", Arrays.toString(partage2));
            for (int i = 0; i < partage2.length; i++) {


            DatabaseReference ref1 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(partage2[i]+"/"+ "lat");
            ref1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    latitude = Double.parseDouble(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { }
            });

            DatabaseReference ref2 = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(partage2[i]+"/"+"lon");
            ref2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    longitude = Double.parseDouble(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) { }
            });
                ajouterunpoint(partage2[i],latitude,longitude);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,partage2[i]+latitude+longitude,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
                           
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w("2", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

and that is my realtime database
[image]

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to be able to read data from the realtime firebase database whenever I want and not just when the data in the database changes

That's already how listeners (and `getData`) in the Realtime Database work. When you call `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, the Firebase SDK immediately calls the server, gets the data from there, and calls your `onDataChange` as soon as it gets the data.